# cypress: select value which exists within the tag

Tags: cypress

Below is my code and I am trying to select a value(`velocity_and_express`) which is given within the `data-bip-collection` attribute. Can anyone please help me on how to select the value from the lists given in `data-bip-collection` ?

```html
<span
  class="best_in_place highlight_on_success funding_type"
  data-bip-attr="funding_type"
  data-bip-collect="[[&quot;velocity_and_express&quot;,&quot;velocity_and_express&quot;],[&quot;velocity&quot;,&quot;velocity&quot;],[&quot;express&quot;,&quot;express&quot;],[&quot;not_yet_set&quot;,&quot;not_yet_set&quot;]]"
  data-bip-confirm="Are you sure you want to change funding type?"
  data-bip-object="company"
  data-bip-original-content="not_yet_set"
  data-bip-type="select"
  data-bip-url="/admin/companies/13"
  data-bip-value="not_yet_set"
  id="best_in_place_company_13_funding_type"
  data-ol-has-click-handler=""
>velocity</span>
```

I tried selecting the option using cy.get() but it did not work

```js
cy.get('[data-bip-attr="funding_type"]')
  .click()
  .get('[data-bip-value="velocity_and_express"]')
  .click()

cy.on('window:confirm', () => true)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the jquery `contains` selector ([docs](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/))
[image: contains selector]

### Example:

```js
cy.get(`[data-bip-collect*="velocity_and_express"]`)
```